# The collection has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I am trying to retrieve all items from a Sharepoint library with `CSOM` and create a list of it. I am sure it has something to do with the order of the code. The question is how?

```
ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
var newList = new List<Item>();
var items = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
context.Load(collListItem);

context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var col in items)
{

    newList.Add(new Item()
    {
        ID = Convert.ToInt32(col["ID"]),

    });
}
```

I get the following error:

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested

Comment: Where does the error appear?

Comment: @Aimnox at foreach (var col in items)

Comment: If you debbug, is `items` null?

Comment: you use some collListItem in context.Load, which is not shown here. What's that?

Comment: assuming you have your oList a valid object you should call `context.Load(items)` not `context.Load(collListItems)`

Comment: @Evk see updated question

Comment: @nizzik this is working thanks. Please post it as answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have loaded the `items` object not the `collListItems` thus your code should look following:

```
ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
var newList = new List<Item>();
var items = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: The first two lines aren't used, and can be omitted as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem, then I recalled ExecuteQuery() below foreach loop and that worked for me

```html
 ListItemCollection recruitmentItems= Recuitment.GetItems(camlQuery);
                cc.Load(recruitmentItems, items => items.Include(
                       x => x.Id,
                       x => x["Title"],
                       x => x["Email"],
                       x => x["Phone"]
                ));
                cc.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (ListItem item in recruitmentItems)
                {
                    ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                    ListItem newItem = Applicant.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
                    newItem["Title"] = item["Title"];
                    newItem["Email"] = item["Email"];
                    newItem["PhoneNumber"] = item["Phone"];
                    newItem.Update();
                }
                cc.ExecuteQuery();
```