# Why is the collection initialized for one site but not the other assuming the correct permissions?

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I am simply trying to connect to a different SharePoint site. This code works perfectly with a specific site but when using a different site with the correct permissions to the site and site list, I receive the following error:

format-default: The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

If the user has full control on the SharePoint list as well as the SharePoint site, why isn't the connection initialized?

I have stepped through the code line by line to see what is being stored to each variable and find that the code throws the error at the following line:

$sharepointlistitems = Get-ListItems -Context $Context -ListTitle $ListName

Here is the code from start to finish for accessing the site. The commented out site works perfectly with the code as is:

````
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client").location))
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.runtime").location))


$admincreds = Get-Credential



$SPCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($admincreds.UserName, $admincreds.Password)




######### Create Sharepoint List Functions ######################################################################

#Function to get items that are not processed
Function Get-ListItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, [String]$ListTitle) {
    $list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
    $qry = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
    #In future query by status to avoid slowing down of program
    $items = $list.GetItems($qry)
    $Context.Load($items)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery() 
    return $items 
}

#Function to update item status
Function Set-ListItemByID([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, [String]$ListTitle, [int]$ItemId, [string]$Status) {
    $list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
    $listitem = $list.GetItemById($ItemId)
    $listitem["AutoAccountCreationStatus"] = $Status
    $listitem.Update();
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

}


##########################   Step 1: Read from SharePoint List and add to an array  ###########################################


#Sets Site, sets list of interest, creates array
#"https://<sitename>.sharepoint.com/sites/Home/TeamSite"
$SiteUrl = "https://<sitename>.sharepoint.com/sites/InfTech"
$ListName = "New Users"

#Setup the context
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Context.Credentials = $SPCredentials

#Getting items from list
$sharepointlistitems = Get-ListItems -Context $Context -ListTitle $ListName 
$sharepointlistitems = $sharepointlistitems | where {$_['AutoAccountCreationStatus'] -eq 'Received'}```
````

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37541669/45375) helps; it's C#, but the error message is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I use Power GUI Script editor to debug PowerShell script usually, we could monitor the variables, it's helpful for troubleshooting.

[image]

Or, you could use [PnP PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) instead,[demo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-using-pnp-powershell)